# Syntax Error in Lisp Loop for defining variables in a loop

Tags: lisp

I am a beginner student who is learning Lisp. I want to turn the loop to the i value using k using the loop statement, but the following error appears. I think I wrote the parentheses correctly, but I don't know why this error occurs.

```
 LOOP: illegal syntax near (SETQ K (1+ K)) in
      (LOOP WHILE (< K I) (SETQ K (1+ K)))
```

Below is my code.

```
(DEFUN promising (i)
    (setq k 1)
    (loop while (< k i) (setq k (1+ k)))
    (return-from promising 1)
 )

promising(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several small things:

1. The `loop` syntax is not 100% correct, you missed a `do` keyword

```
(loop while (< k i) do (setq k (1+ k)))
                    ^^
                    do keyword is missing!
```

2. The syntax for the function call `promising(2)` is also incorrect

```
(promising 2)
```

3. The `return-from` thing is unusual

The first reason is that the return value is always `1`, in your case, you probably want to return `k`.

```
(DEFUN promising (i)
    (setq k 1)
    (loop while (< k i) (setq k (1+ k)))
    (return-from promising 1))
                           ^
                           Always return 1
```

The second reason is you don't *need* a `return-from`, the last value of a `defun` form will be given to the function caller.

```
(DEFUN promising (i)
    (setq k 1)
    (loop while (< k i) do (setq k (1+ k)))
    k)
    ^
    The last value will be returned to the function caller
```

4. The `k` variable should be defined *locally* and not use a *global* definition

The final code could be something like this:

```
(defun promising (i)
  (let ((k 1))
    (loop while (< k i) do (setq k (1+ k)))
    ;; return value
    k))

(promising 2)
```

This should return:

```
2
```